# Spark JoinWithCassandraTable on TimeStamp partition key STUCK

Tags: mysql, scala, cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to filter on a small part of a huge C* table by using:

```
    val snapshotsFiltered = sc.parallelize(startDate to endDate).map(TableKey(_)).joinWithCassandraTable("listener","snapshots_tspark")

    println("Done Join")
    //*******
    //get only the snapshots and create rdd temp table
    val jsons = snapshotsFiltered.map(_._2.getString("snapshot"))
    val jsonSchemaRDD = sqlContext.jsonRDD(jsons)
    jsonSchemaRDD.registerTempTable("snapshots_json")
```

With:

```
    case class TableKey(created: Long) //(created, imei, when)--> created = partititon key | imei, when = clustering key
```

And the cassandra table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE listener.snapshots_tspark (
created timestamp,
imei text,
when timestamp,
snapshot text,
PRIMARY KEY (created, imei, when) ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (imei ASC, when ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

The problem is that the process freezes after the println done with no errors on spark master ui.

```
[Stage 0:>                                                                                                                                (0 + 2) / 2]
```

Won`t the Join work with timestamp as the partition key? Why it freezes?

Comment: Did you check if there is enough resource for the job to run?

Comment: @eliasah Yes. Memory: 5.5 GB Total, 512.0 MB Used

Comment: If the collection snapshotsFiltered returns empty the next stage will stuck?

Comment: No, that's not the reason. It may get stuck from lack of resource mainly. Here it might be from the complexity of the query plan you are tyring to execute.

Comment: @eliasah why is it complex? It only suppose to cluster on the created timestamp and bring the ones that created > startDate and startDate to endDate < endDate. The whole point in using JoinWithCassandraTable (and not sc.cassandraTable("listener","snapshots_test_c").where("created >= "+ startDate + " and created <= "+ endDate) ) is to save time.

Comment: When I using where (or even worse - filter) it takes 10 houres because the spark loades the whole table to the memory... I need to push the job back to cassandra  and that is why I want to use the JoinWithCassandraTable. As described here http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/zen-art-spark-maintenance

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try to break the steps of your table join?

Comment: @eliasah Yes. It went fine. It freezes after the Join done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93290/discussion-between-eliasah-and-rada).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using:

```
sc.parallelize(startDate to endDate)
```

With the startData and endDate as Longs generated from Dates by the format:

```
("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

I made spark to build a huge array (100,000+ objects) to join with C* table and it didn't stuck at all- C* worked hard to make the join happen and return the data.

Finally, I changed my range to:

```
case class TableKey(created_dh: String)
val data = Array("2015-10-29 12:00:00", "2015-10-29 13:00:00", "2015-10-29 14:00:00", "2015-10-29 15:00:00")
val snapshotsFiltered = sc.parallelize(data, 2).map(TableKey(_)).joinWithCassandraTable("listener","snapshots_tnew")
```

And it is ok now.