# Cassandra: Selecting a Range of TimeUUIDs using the DataStax Java Driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

The use case that we are working to solve with Cassandra is this: We need to retrieve a list of entity UUIDs that have been updated within a certain time range within the last 90 days. Imagine that we're building a document tracking system, so our relevant entity is a Document, whose key is a UUID.

The query we need to support in this use case is: *Find all Document UUIDs that have changed between StartDateTime and EndDateTime.*

**Question 1: What's the best Cassandra table design to support this query?**

I think the answer is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE document_change_events (
    event_uuid TIMEUUID,
    document_uuid uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY ((event_uuid), document_uuid)
) WITH default_time_to_live='7776000';
```

And given that we can't do range queries on partition keys, we'd need to use the `token()` method. As such the query would then be:

```
SELECT document_uuid 
 WHERE token(event_uuid) > token(minTimeuuid(?)) 
   AND token(event_uuid) < token(maxTimeuuid(?))
```

For example:

```
SELECT document_uuid 
 WHERE token(event_uuid) > token(minTimeuuid('2015-05-10 00:00+0000')) 
   AND token(event_uuid) < token(maxTimeuuid('2015-05-20 00:00+0000'))
```

**Question 2: I can't seem to get the following Java code using DataStax's driver to reliability return the correct results.**

If I run the following code 10 times pausing 30 seconds between, I will then have 10 rows in this table:

```
private void addEvent() {

    String cql = "INSERT INTO document_change_events (event_uuid, document_uuid) VALUES(?,?)";

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = cassandraSession.prepare(cql);
    BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(preparedStatement);
    boundStatement.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ANY);

    boundStatement.setUUID("event_uuid", UUIDs.timeBased());
    boundStatement.setUUID("document_uuid", UUIDs.random());

    cassandraSession.execute(boundStatement);

}
```

Here are the results:

```
cqlsh:> select event_uuid, dateOf(event_uuid), document_uuid from document_change_events;

 event_uuid                           | dateOf(event_uuid)       | document_uuid
--------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------
 414decc0-0014-11e5-93a9-51f9a7931084 | 2015-05-21 18:51:09-0500 | 92b6fb6a-9ded-47b0-a91c-68c63f45d338
 9abb4be0-0014-11e5-93a9-51f9a7931084 | 2015-05-21 18:53:39-0500 | 548b320a-10f6-409f-a921-d4a1170a576e
 6512b960-0014-11e5-93a9-51f9a7931084 | 2015-05-21 18:52:09-0500 | 970e5e77-1e07-40ea-870a-84637c9fc280
 53307a20-0014-11e5-93a9-51f9a7931084 | 2015-05-21 18:51:39-0500 | 11b4a49c-b73d-4c8d-9f88-078a6f303167
 ac9e0050-0014-11e5-93a9-51f9a7931084 | 2015-05-21 18:54:10-0500 | b29e7915-7c17-4900-b784-8ac24e9e72e2
 88d7fb30-0014-11e5-93a9-51f9a7931084 | 2015-05-21 18:53:09-0500 | c8188b73-1b97-4b32-a897-7facdeecea35
 0ba5cf70-0014-11e5-93a9-51f9a7931084 | 2015-05-21 18:49:39-0500 | a079b30f-be80-4a99-ae0e-a784d82f0432
 76f56dd0-0014-11e5-93a9-51f9a7931084 | 2015-05-21 18:52:39-0500 | 3b593ca6-220c-4a8b-8c16-27dc1fb5adde
 1d88f910-0014-11e5-93a9-51f9a7931084 | 2015-05-21 18:50:09-0500 | ec155e0b-39a5-4d2f-98f0-0cd7a5a07ec8
 2f6b3850-0014-11e5-93a9-51f9a7931084 | 2015-05-21 18:50:39-0500 | db42271b-04f2-45d1-9ae7-0c8f9371a4db

(10 rows)
```

But if I then run this code:

```
private static void retrieveEvents(Instant startInstant, Instant endInstant) {

    String cql = "SELECT document_uuid FROM document_change_events " + 
                 "WHERE token(event_uuid) > token(?) AND token(event_uuid) < token(?)";

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = cassandraSession.prepare(cql);
    BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(preparedStatement);
    boundStatement.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM);

    boundStatement.bind(UUIDs.startOf(Date.from(startInstant).getTime()),
                        UUIDs.endOf(Date.from(endInstant).getTime()));

    ResultSet resultSet = cassandraSession.execute(boundStatement);

    if (resultSet == null) {
      System.out.println("None found.");
      return;
    }

    while (!resultSet.isExhausted()) {
      System.out.println(resultSet.one().getUUID("document_uuid"));
    }

}
```

It only retrieves three results:

```
3b593ca6-220c-4a8b-8c16-27dc1fb5adde
ec155e0b-39a5-4d2f-98f0-0cd7a5a07ec8
db42271b-04f2-45d1-9ae7-0c8f9371a4db
```

Why didn't it retrieve all 10 results? And what do I need to change to achieve the correct results to support this use case?

For reference, I've tested this against dsc-2.1.1, dse-4.6 and using the DataStax Java Driver v2.1.6.

Comment: This answer may help you : [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883202/time-series-data-selecting-range-with-maxtimeuuid-mintimeuuid-in-cassandra)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*First of all, please only ask one question at a time.  Both of your questions here could easily stand on their own.  I know these are related, but it just makes the readers come down with a case of **tl;dr**.*

I'll answer your **2nd question** first, because the answer ties into a fundamental understanding that is central to getting the data model correct.  When I INSERT your rows and run the following query, this is what I get:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT document_uuid FROM document_change_events 
WHERE token(event_uuid) > token(minTimeuuid('2015-05-10 00:00-0500')) 
  AND token(event_uuid) < token(maxTimeuuid('2015-05-22 00:00-0500'));

 document_uuid
--------------------------------------
 a079b30f-be80-4a99-ae0e-a784d82f0432
 3b593ca6-220c-4a8b-8c16-27dc1fb5adde
 ec155e0b-39a5-4d2f-98f0-0cd7a5a07ec8
 db42271b-04f2-45d1-9ae7-0c8f9371a4db

(4 rows)
```

Which is similar to what you are seeing.  Why didn't that return all 10?  Well, the answer becomes apparent when I include `token(event_uuid)` in my SELECT:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT token(event_uuid),document_uuid FROM document_change_events WHERE token(event_uuid) > token(minTimeuuid('2015-05-10 00:00-0500')) AND token(event_uuid) < token(maxTimeuuid('2015-05-22 00:00-0500'));

 token(event_uuid)    | document_uuid
----------------------+--------------------------------------
 -2112897298583224342 | a079b30f-be80-4a99-ae0e-a784d82f0432
  2990331690803078123 | 3b593ca6-220c-4a8b-8c16-27dc1fb5adde
  5049638908563824288 | ec155e0b-39a5-4d2f-98f0-0cd7a5a07ec8
  5577339174953240576 | db42271b-04f2-45d1-9ae7-0c8f9371a4db

(4 rows)
```

Cassandra stores partition keys (`event_uuid` in your case) in order by their hashed token value.  You can see this when using the `token` function.  Cassandra generates partition tokens with a process called [consistent hashing](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeHashing_c.html) to ensure even cluster distribution.  In other words, querying by token range doesn't make sense unless the actual (hashed) token values are meaningful to your application.

Getting back to your **first question**, this means you will have to find a different column to partition on.  My suggestion is to use a timeseries mechanism called a "date bucket."  Picking the date bucket can be tricky, as it depends on your requirements and query patterns...so that's really up to you to pick a useful one.

For the purposes of this example, I'll pick "month."  So I'll re-create your table partitioning on `month` and clustering by event_uuid:

```
CREATE TABLE document_change_events2 (
    event_uuid TIMEUUID,
    document_uuid uuid,
    month text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((month),event_uuid, document_uuid)
) WITH default_time_to_live='7776000';
```

Now I can query by a date range, when also filtering by `month`:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT document_uuid FROM document_change_events2 
WHERE month='201505'
  AND event_uuid > minTimeuuid('2015-05-10 00:00-0500')
  AND event_uuid < maxTimeuuid('2015-05-22 00:00-0500');

 document_uuid
--------------------------------------
 a079b30f-be80-4a99-ae0e-a784d82f0432
 ec155e0b-39a5-4d2f-98f0-0cd7a5a07ec8
 db42271b-04f2-45d1-9ae7-0c8f9371a4db
 92b6fb6a-9ded-47b0-a91c-68c63f45d338
 11b4a49c-b73d-4c8d-9f88-078a6f303167
 970e5e77-1e07-40ea-870a-84637c9fc280
 3b593ca6-220c-4a8b-8c16-27dc1fb5adde
 c8188b73-1b97-4b32-a897-7facdeecea35
 548b320a-10f6-409f-a921-d4a1170a576e
 b29e7915-7c17-4900-b784-8ac24e9e72e2

(10 rows)
```

Again, `month` may not work for your application.  So put some thought behind coming up with an appropriate column to partition on, and then you should be able to solve this.

Comment: Good point about separate questions. I was thinking that my problem was something slightly incorrect with the code, so that was my focus but I wanted to open up responses to include more correct designs.

With regards to the tokens, I was under the impression that timeuuids generated sequential tokens, but clearly that's not correct!

Thanks for the recommendations on time bucketing. I just implemented the solution and it's worked well thus far.